# Using Type instead of specific class

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
if (((Classes.ProductGroup)o).ToString().Contains(comboBox.Text)) 
   return true;
else 
   return false;
```

Now I want not to specify the part `Classes.ProductGroup`. I want to make it universal.

How can I replace the part `Classes.ProductGroup` with a `Type` object?

```
Type type = typeof(Classes.ProductGroup);
```

Something similar to this:

```
if (((type)o).ToString().Contains(comboBox.Text))
```

Is this possible?

Here is the complete method code:

```
private void FilterPGsinComboBox(object obj)  
{
    if (!Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(new FilterPGsinComboBoxDelegate(this.FilterPGsinComboBox),obj);
        return;
    }
    Type type = ((Dictionary<ComboBox, Type>)obj).First().Value;
    ComboBox comboBox = ((Dictionary<ComboBox, Type>)obj).First().Key;
    comboBox.IsDropDownOpen = true;
    CollectionView itemsViewOriginal = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(comboBox.ItemsSource);

    itemsViewOriginal.Filter = ((o) =>
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox.Text)) 
            return true;
        else
        {
            if (((Classes.ProductGroup)o).ToString().Contains(comboBox.Text)) 
                return true;
            else 
                return false;
        }
    });

    itemsViewOriginal.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: all objects have `ToString()`. cast is redundant

Comment: what is `o` and please provide what function you want to achieve

Comment: Use [generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx)

Comment: @ASh - unless that class or one of its ancestors has shadowed the method. (But that does raise the question of why someone would think to do so)

Comment: @dns_nx, `o` is an `object`. if `o==null` return false else call `ToString()` without cast. `return o.ToString().Contains(comboBox.Text);`

Comment: Yes, but how to cast `o` to the given type and then perform the search?

Comment: @dns_nx, why is it so important to have concrete type?

Comment: @ASh You're completely right. The cast is unnecessary. I tried it and it works as expected! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string ToString()` method is defined in the base `Object` class. cast to concrete type is redundant.

```
string filter = comboBox.Text;

itemsViewOriginal.Filter = o => String.IsNullOrEmpty(filter) || 
                                o != null && o.ToString().Contains(filter);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use generics and build a method like

```
public bool ClassNameContainString<T>(string text) where T : class
{
    var containsString = typeof(T).ToString().Contains(text);

    return containsString;
}
```

If you want to make this method case insensitive change the logic to

```
var containsString = typeof(T).ToString().ToLower().Contains(text.ToLower());
```

Comment: My understanding was that the OP wanted to do `((T)o).ToString()`. Its not entirely clear but changing from a cast of an object to using a type seems less likely than changing from casting to a fixed object to a variable object.

Comment: but doesn't this function misses the object `o`? and then I'm in the situation I was before...

Comment: Chris, you're right. I wanted to cast `o` as given type.